# Adding Object to Array Using a Method

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Edit: I'm stupid, sorry. Thought JavaScript and Java were the same thing. Anyway, I still need help with this. I'm using this method in my Course class:

```
public void addStudent(Meerkan_Student student)
```

Let me know if I need to provide more information! I will reply to your comment instantly as I'm just sitting here, on my laptop, stumped.

Comment: @azurefrog Wait how though? I've seen countless websites saying otherwise. Did I misunderstand something?

Comment: Were you looking for _Javascript_? That's a different language.

Comment: @Tom Oh wow, yes I was. For two semesters now I've been thinking Java Script is just another term for Java, but somehow this is the only time it became a problem. Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure you are not confusing things with PHP or JavaScript? Java arrays don't have a 'push' method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is how you would define your array:

```
Meerkan_Student[] arr = new Meerkan_Student[12] // you can replace 12 with any size you want.
```

this is how you would add a student to the array:

```
public void addStudent(Meerkan_Student student) {
    int i = 0;
    while(i < arr.length && arr[i] != null)
       i++;
    if(i < arr.length)
       arr[i] = student;
}
```

**if it's an ArrayList,**

Defination:

```
 List<Meerkan_Student> arr = new ArrayList<>();
```

Method:

```
 public void addStudent(Meerkan_Student student) {
    arr.add(student);
 }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this! I just had another question. I need to have another method that adds just the student name to the array, not an object. How would I go about doing that? So: public void addStudentName(String studentName)

Comment: @M.Erkan same as above, just create a list or an array of type `String` instead of `Meerkan_Student` and can you please accept the above answer and upvote it if it worked for you ?